# How to use physics body editor's Loader to load fixture in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

sorry about this silly question, but i have no idea what do after creating body fixture from physics body editor software,aurelions ribbon. i don't know how to use loader, i just tried

```
BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(
                Gdx.files.internal("data/player.json"));

        // 1. Create a BodyDef, as usual.
        BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
        bd.position.set(0, 0);
        bd.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

        // 2. Create a FixtureDef, as usual.
        FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
        fd.density = 1;
        fd.friction = 0.5f;
        fd.restitution = 0.3f;
```

but showing me error at line 1 BodyEditorLoader is unknown, and i don't know how to make it know to android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this class to your project, (although there is a slight chance it might not work due to changes in the `libGDX` API but it should be fairly easy to use):

https://gist.github.com/grulg/8691e7ee7709367ce165

Comment: yes,it worked.thanks. i got error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, but i solved it by placing world initialization before Loader.

Answer (score 0):

Three simple steps :

> 1. Create body editor loader

```
BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("data/player.json"));
```

> 2. Create body definition then create body by using that def from physics world.

```
 BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
 bdef.position.set(0,0);
 bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
 Body body = world.createBody(bdef);
```

> 3. Create Fixture definition and attach to body

```
FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
fdef.density = 1;
fdef.friction = 0.5f;
fdef.restitution = 0.5f;

float scale =.1f;   
loader.attachFixture(body, "Name", fdef, scale);
```

Comment: @Tojrah "Name" is used to retrieve right fixture from the loaded file.(here `player.json` is the file name that can contains number of fixture)

Comment: Thanks. It helped